# Atualizar Text vinculado a um DataBinding

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Tenho a seguinte propriedade vinculada a um label, onde o valor dessa propriedade aparece no campo texto. Assim:

```
 this.labelPedidosHoje.DataBindings.Add("Text", pedidosIntegrados, "PedidosIntegradosModelo.PedidosIntegradosDia",true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

Quando inicio a aplicação os valores aparecem perfeitamente.

Mas infelizmente quando mudo o valor da propriedade o mesmo não replica na tela (campo text).

Alguém sabe me dizer como dar um refresh no campo text da tela para aparecer o valor atualizado ?

Nota:
1- Quando esse valor é atualizado eu chamo o método OnPropertyChanged para avisar que o valor da propriedade mudou.

2 - Quando efetuo um debug olho o valor da propriedade, e o mesmo está com o valor atualizado. Sendo assim, só preciso atualizar o campo text.

Answer (score 2):

Segue exemplo da solução que encontrei. Obrigado ! @MaiconCarraro.

```
 using System;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Drawing;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Windows.Forms;
 using System.Collections;


namespace System_Windows_Forms_UpdateBinding
{
class Form1 : Form
{
    // Declare the objects on the form. 
    private Label label1;
    private Label label2;
    private TextBox textBox1;
    private TextBox textBox2;
    private Button button1;
    private BindingSource bindingSource1;
    ArrayList states;

    public Form1()
    {
        // Basic form setup. 
        this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.textBox2 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 18);
        this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(119, 38);
        this.button1.Text = "RemoveAt(0)";
        this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
        this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(55, 75);
        this.textBox1.ReadOnly = true;
        this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(119, 20);
        this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 110);
        this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(43, 14);
        this.label1.Text = "Capital:";
        this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 78);
        this.label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(34, 14);
        this.label2.Text = "State:";
        this.textBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(55, 110);
        this.textBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(119, 20);
        this.textBox2.ReadOnly = true;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(292, 273);
        this.Controls.Add(this.textBox2);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label2);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
        this.Text = "Form1";

        // Create an ArrayList containing some of the State objects.
        states = new ArrayList();
        states.Add(new State("California", "Sacramento"));
        states.Add(new State("Oregon", "Salem"));
        states.Add(new State("Washington", "Olympia"));
        states.Add(new State("Idaho", "Boise"));
        states.Add(new State("Utah", "Salt Lake City"));
        states.Add(new State("Hawaii", "Honolulu"));
        states.Add(new State("Colorado", "Denver"));
        states.Add(new State("Montana", "Helena"));

        bindingSource1 = new BindingSource();

        // Bind BindingSource1 to the list of states.
        bindingSource1.DataSource = states;

        // Bind the two text boxes to properties of State.
        textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource1, "Name");
        textBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource1, "Capital");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // If items remain in the list, remove the first item.  
        if (states.Count > 0)
        {
            states.RemoveAt(0);

            // Call ResetBindings to update the textboxes.
            bindingSource1.ResetBindings(false);
        }
    }

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.Run(new Form1());

    }

    // The State class to add to the ArrayList. 
    private class State
    {
        private string stateName;
        public string Name 
        {
            get {return stateName;}
        }

        private string stateCapital;
        public string Capital 
        {
            get {return stateCapital;}
        }

        public State ( string name, string capital)
        {
            stateName = name;
            stateCapital = capital;
        }
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

`DataBindings` não tem efeito enquanto o control não perder o foco, se você quiser forçar a ação dele pode fazer algo do tipo:

```
this.labelPedidosHoje.DataBindings.Add("Text", pedidosIntegrados, "PedidosIntegradosModelo.PedidosIntegradosDia",true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
this.labelPedidosHoje.DataBindings[0].WriteValue(); // força
```

Assumindo que você só adiciono um único Binding, por isso o `zero`.

Comment: Então, esse controle não atualiza o valor, mas os outros que tenho em minha aplicação sim. Será que existe alguma forma mais elegante de fazer isso ?

Comment: Cara, consegui resolver. Segue o link para quem tiver o mesmo problema: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f61k6akt(v=vs.110).aspx. Obrigado !

Comment: @EmersonBrito Converte seu link em uma resposta aqui porque ai mesmo que o link fique fora do ar o pessoal consegue ver a solução aqui